# How can bzr know about launchpad?

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I'm a *git* user, and I'd like to clone a repository for a project hosted on *Launchpad*, which uses *bzr* instead.

On the guide they suggest me to run `bzr branch lp:zim` (where "zim" is the project). I'm wondering how is *bzr* aware of what "lp" means. Is this thanks to some plugin which is installed by default on my *Mint Linux* (which is basically a Ubuntu in disguise, so that's likely)? Are there more of these magic keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a built in command for bzr. Remember bzr and Launchpad are both primarily written by the same company (canonical) and bzr has a large amount of support for Launchpad.

Another such keyword is `bzr branch ubuntu:package`, which gets the version of the package in the current Ubuntu release, from Launchpad.

[This page](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/tutorials/using_bazaar_with_launchpad.html) has more information about Launchpad integration.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin shipped with bzr by default (see bzrlib/plugins/launchpad in the source). This registers a custom handler for the "lp:" URL scheme (and similarly for the "ubuntu:" scheme).

Comment: The plugin explaination is what I wanted to hear :) The `lp` thing sounded me so weird...